# Vote undo shouldn't subtract 10 if you've exceeded number of votes for rep limit

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Just noticed this, and I'm filing it as a bug although feel free to change it to `feature-request` rather than `status-bydesign`.

I was nearing my reputation gain limit for the day, posted an answer and received enough votes to take me "above" the reputation cap.  My summary showed 7 upvotes for that answer, with 50 reputation earned.  I refreshed the page and it dropped to 6 upvotes with 40 reputation earned and I'm now 10 points away from the daily reputation limit.

Clearly, someone who's vote counted towards my limit retracted said vote and their 10 points were taken away. I think a recalc would make more sense - I've clearly gained enough votes to hit the limit, wouldn't it be smarter for the system to figure out that I've still got at least 2 votes left to count towards my rep?

Comment: The rep limit should be 200 not 50.

Comment: @googletorp: I meant for that particular answer, I'll clarify.

Comment: Then the cap wouldn't really be a cap, would it?

Comment: @Juan: seriously? of course it would be a cap, I wouldn't be able to earn more reputation than the cap...

Comment: it would be a "special cap"

Comment: @Juan: I don't see how it would be "special" - I've earned enough votes to achieve the cap, and no other votes other than those involved in a recalculation would count, and if a manual recalc would solve this problem anyway then why not make it automatic as part of the vote-undo process?

Comment: Gee it sure would be nice if there were regular system-wide reputation recalcs... *pines in the corner*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of [the recent reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), your reputation will be adjusted within 5 minutes in this case.  If a vote cast on the *same* day that affected you hitting the reputation cap (i.e. which actually gave you rep that day) is deleted, your rep will be queued for an adjustment so you'll get back to the cap if that's what needs to happen.

Note that if a vote that was cast on a *previous* day was removed, the subtraction [will still continue to persist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262031/377214), as it's as if you never received the vote *on the day it was originally cast*.

Comment: So which was harder, coding the new rep changes, or updating all these meta posts? :)

Comment: @AdamRackis - at least I'm done (far as I know) coding the rep changes...so meta I'd say :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by flagging one of your posts and requesting a recalc to a moderator.

That would regenerate your reputation from scratch and would take you back to 200 for the day.

Keep in mind that you could lose reputation from deleted posts from other days, you can check your reputation here: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation (replace stackoverflow for the trilogy site you want)

Comment: Wouldn't the recalc fix this issue even if it is done a month later? It doesn't need to be done immediately.

Comment: Yes @dev, that's true (I don't imply otherwise)

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know this could at least be solved by contacting a mod. It's not super important, the mods have enough to do and I'm sure I can make up the 10 points to reach the rep limit anyway. I just thought it was worth raising a bug report/feature request about it.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to have been a different problem than I'd originally thought, so it's been [posted as a new bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371764/142445). The remainder of this answer can probably be ignored, but is left here for reference.

---

The adjustement described in [Nick Craver's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123884/142445) does not seem to be <s>working</s> displaying correctly:

[image: yesterday]

This should sum to 215, but it sums only to 205, or 190 without the accept points.

That said, it's hard to debug what's going on here and be totally sure that the issue was that downvote. It look as if +10 was latter added for the upvote just after the downvote but 10 was somehow removed from the scores before the downvote; previously the scores had looked like this:

[image: during day]

Note that in the first image above we have a total of 190 points for upvotes before the downvote, but in the second we have a total of 200 points before the downvote.

<s>Is there any way to get the vote-by-vote timeline back again? I saw it once for part of the day, as you see in the second image, but I cannot get it back again. (Had I known this information would vanish forever I would have captured part of the titles in the screenshot.)</s>

The log for the day from `/reputation` shows:

```
 2     22183 (10)
 2     22183 (10)
 2     22204 (10)
 2     22183 (10)
 2     22204 (10)
 2     14016 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22183 (10)
 2     22183 (10)
 2     22197 (10)
 2     22200 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22204 (10)
 2     22183 (10)
 2     22210 (10)
 2     22183 [10]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22207 [0]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22197 [0]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22200 [0]
 1     22200 [15]
 2     22183 [0]
 2     22200 [0]
 2     22204 [0]
 2     14016 [0]
-- 2021-11-09 rep +215  = 18790
```

I'm not entirely sure how to interpret the above data (the meaning of parentheses vs. square brackets is particularly mysterious), but this properly shows 215, my reputation total as displayed in the header is currently 18,790, and 18790 - 18575 = 215. So perhaps the problem on my user page is a display issue?

Comment: What amount of rep does https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/reputation show?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for that URL; I had no idea that it existed. I've updated this answer.

Comment: A note to downvoters: if you care to leave a comment on what you think is wrong with this bug report, I will be happy to try to remedy the problem.

Comment: It makes sense now. The vote that was reversed was cast on a *previous* day, so it's as if that vote was never cast in the first place. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360864/why-wasnt-this-upvote-counted-toward-rep and its duplicate target for more info.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think some may do so because this isn't an answer to the question. It'd have been better posted as a new question (though in this case would have been closed as a duplicate).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Hm. I had assumed that the unupvote immediately followed by an upvote on 14016 ("What is DRAM refresh...") was an accidental unupvote that someone corrected. But if I understand you correctly, what I would find here if I had a previous version of the `/reputation` page to compare with is that a previous day's `(10)` line is changed to `(0)` or vanishes (with, presumably something else changed to add 10 if that day had exceeded the cap), and there's no record of that unupvote in the current day's listing in the `/reputation` page?

Comment: And so it seems that the problem here may be that there's something that _does_ display that unupvote in the user page, and that -10 is incorrectly included in the day's total reputation gain displayed there?

Comment: I might suggest reporting this apparent bug in a new post instead, given that the original question and answer here are almost a decade old.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, it would seem that this is not at all the bug I originally thought it was. I've posted a new question and updated the head of this answer to point to it. Thanks.