# Can the max reputation rule cause reputation loss for zero-sum-actions?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, daily-reputation-limit

A simple scenario that is - as far as I know - not described in the reputation [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

1. Say user *A* **posts** a question/answer on a SE community;
2. User *B* **upvotes** the post, but since user *A* already achieved the maximum reputation that day, it doesn't count;
3. Later user *A* **changes** his/her post;
4. User *B* rereads the post, and thinks it is lacking something (he/she didn't see before). He/she decides to **retract his/her upvote**.

Of course the sequence of events is quite unlikely, but with thousands of actions, even an unlikely sequence will occur eventually.

In a normal situation (without maximum reputation), this would mean *A* loses his first earned **+10** (or other value). The sequence is thus a zero-sum: after the sequence it is as if only step *1* and *3* are executed: the users would thus be in the same state as **before** (except a post has been made and edited). But since user *A* never received any reputation for the upvote, it would be rather strange to lose reputation.

Users probably have no means to see whether this scenario holds, I was just wondering, because modeling the reputation system resulted in some open questions regarding the reputation system.

Comment: Actually, there was a bug causing a temporary loss of reputation, but [it was fixed long ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53710/vote-undo-shouldnt-subtract-10-if-youve-exceeded-number-of-votes-for-rep-limit).

Answer (score 8):

The reputation cap will not cause anyone to *lose* reputation, no. Undoing a vote does not result in a new vote (type *undo*), but rather in the vote being removed as if it had not been cast.

As such, undoing a vote *removes the vote from your score*. If it didn't add points before, undoing the vote (as if it hasn't been cast) will not result in points being subtracted.

Note that this also applies for votes that give you less than 10 points; say you had hit the cap, had been downvoted, then received that upvote. The upvote gave +2 points, undoing it means the vote is no longer there and you return to the situation you lost 2 points after hitting the cap.

The reputation cap is also [re-calculated after votes are undone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123884). If a vote that did give you +10 points is undone, a next, *later* vote that was capped and gave you +0 points would now count and give you +10.